# Checkbox set as radio button second click glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a function to make my checkboxes as radio buttons with addition that they can be deselected.
The problem I'm encountering is that when same box is clicked for second time bit faster (not a fast double click) it doesn't do anything, like it hasn't caught the event.

They go in multiples by two, which share names.

```
checkbox name 1
checkbox2 name 1

checkbox3 name 2
checkbox4 name 2 ....
```

This is my function, it works well, aside from that glitch.

```
$('#MyDiv').find('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        return;
    }
    $('#MyDiv').find('input[type="checkbox"][name=' + $(this).attr('name') + ']').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Html example:

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <div>
        <p>
            <input id="MyDivUsage_Yes" type="checkbox" name="MyDivUsage"  />
            <label for="MyDivUsage_Yes">Yes</label>
            <input id="MyDivUsage_No" type="checkbox" name="MyDivUsage" />
            <label for="MyDivUsage_No">No</label>
        </p>

    </div>
</div>​
```

For some reason it wont work on jsfiddle.

Comment: I think that you have already identified your problem... the event "fumble". I don't know a way around this however so I too am looking forward to the responses.

Comment: Could you add some html or setup an example here: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var checked = {};
    $('.desectable-radio').each(function (index) {
        checked[index] = this.checked;
        $(this).click(function () {
            if (checked[index])
                this.checked = false;
            for (var i in checked) {
                checked[i] = false;
            }
            checked[index] = this.checked;
        });
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dFDeX/1/

Comment: This works quite well! No fumble at all not even in IE. I just have to check something more :)

Comment: This is all around solution it would seem. Although it actually using radios the functionality is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it at least could be more efficient :

```
$('#MyDiv').find('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4MVK5/1/)

or a little more native JS:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]', '#MyDiv').on('click', function() {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByName(this.name);
    for (var i=0; i<boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[i] != this) boxes[i].checked = false;
    }
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4MVK5/2/)

Comment: Thanks I'll go ahead and test this out.

Comment: + since code is excellent example, and it works for all browsers properly except for IE.